# Are the vectors that form a basis for the null space of $A$ always linearly independent with the vectors that form the basis for the row space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

After doing this question, I am surprised to learn that the vectors that form the basis for the null space of $A$, $(1,0,1,0)^T$ and $(1,-3,0,1)^T$ is also linearly independent with the vectors that form a basis for the row space of $A$, $(1,0,-1,-1)^T$ and $(0,1,0,3)^T$.

Is this always true in general or does this only apply in this particular example? Would the result still hold if the row space is replaced with column space?

EDIT:

I am also interested to find out alternative (and quicker) means to determine if the 4 vectors are linearly independent. In this case, I arranged the vectors into column matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}
 &1& 1 & 1  & 0 \\
 0 & -3 &0 &1 \\
 1 & 0 &-1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 3
\end{array}
\right]$

After interchanging some rows, I end up with:

$\left[ \begin{array}
 &1& 1 & 1  & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &-1 &3 \\
 1 & 0 &-1 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$

which, by inspection, I see can be reduced to the identity matrix. Hence, the column vectors are linearly independent. Is there a quicker way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No.

By definition, the matrix product with a vector from the null space is zero, which means that
for every row vector, the *standard scalar product* between the vector from the null space and the row vector is zero.
In other words, the null space is orthogonal to the row space, hence your observation about linear independence.

In a more general context, one may consider other fields than $\mathbb R$ and there is no such thing as a
standard scalar product. For eymple, over a field of characteristic $2$, the null space of
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ contains the row vector(s)!

For your last quetsion, you should see from your own example that it doesn't even make sense:
The null space is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ and the column vectors ar in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clear and easy to follow. I've added another question (I wanted to add it earlier but then the site went into maintenance). Could you please address it too?